# Not managing to find a way to use is_page() with a variable inside storing an array

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, conditional-statements

Building a Wordpress plugin here. I have a text form in which user can insert pages IDs - separated by commas - to display a BAR in it.

Then I set a variable to get those Ids and I am trying to use this variable with the conditional tag "is_page( array() )".

Problem is, the BAR is showing only on the page related to the first ID given by the user. It is strange, cause I echoed the variable and it is showing all Id's given, separated by commas. Hardcoding the IDs, like this "is_page( array(207,306) )", I get the result I want and the BAR is displaying on the 2 pages related to the IDs. But when I use "is_page( array($setting_value) )", only page related to the first ID is showing the BAR, even when "echo $setting_value" results in 207,306.

Can anybody show me what is wrong?

Here's the parts of the code related to it:

```
//getting the IDs
$setting_value = esc_attr( (get_option( 'ma-singular' ) ) );

    if ( $home != 'onlyHome' ) {
    echo "<input class='text' type='text' name='ma-singular' value='" . $setting_value . "' />";

    }

//displaying the BAR on the PAGES related to the IDs typed by users

$singular = esc_attr (get_option ( 'ma-singular' ));

if ( $home != 'onlyHome' && is_page( array($singular) ) ) {


    if ( is_user_logged_in() && !empty($alttext) ) {

            echo '<div class="ma-' . $cor = get_option( 'ma-cor') . 
            '" style="background-color:' . $cordefundo =  get_option( 'ma-fundo' ) . 
            '">' . $alttext . '</div>';

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode `$singular` before using it. It's going wrong because what you think is an array of values is a single value inside the array.

Let's say for example 'ma-singular' = 127,135,189.

`array( $singular )` would be equal to `array( '127,135,189' )` when what you need is `array( 127, 135, 189 )`.

So to fix this you would do:

```
$singular = esc_attr (get_option ( 'ma-singular' ));

if ( ! empty( $singular ) ) { 
    $singular = explode( ',', $singular );
}

if ( $home != 'onlyHome' && is_page( $singular ) ) {
```